# I'm trying to get the Highest sum in JS , but I keep running into this error

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, debugging

I'm  trying to get the highest sum, but I keep running into this error
"for(let i = 1; i <          nums.length; i++) { ^  TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')"

Please help to debug. I have tried for many hours but couldn't find the problem.

```
let getAverage = function(nums) {

  let sum = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
    let el = nums[i];
    sum += el;
  }
  return sum / nums.length;
}



let highestAverage = function(numsList) {

  let highAvg = getAverage(highestAverage[0]);
  let highAvgIndex = 0;

  for (let i = 0; i < numsList.length; i++) { `it seems there is a problem is this part`

    let currentAvg = getAverage(highestAverage[i]);

    if (currentAvg > highAvg) {

      highAvg = currentAvg;
      highAvgIndex = i;
    }

  };

  return highAvgIndex;
}

`there are the array and the values of output`
const arrayA = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
const arrayB = [10000, -9998];
const arrayC = [2, 100, 55, 19];
const arrayD = [4, 8, 12];


if (getAverage(arrayA) === 3);
if (getAverage(arrayB) === 1);
if (getAverage(arrayC) === 44);
if (getAverage(arrayD) === 8);

if (highestAverage([arrayA, arrayB, arrayC, arrayD]) === 2);
if (highestAverage([arrayA, arrayB]) === 0);
if (highestAverage([arrayA, arrayD]) === 1);
```

Comment: `highestAverage` is a function, you're trying to access 0th index of it, so that's expected

Answer (score 1):

Your code is wrong. If you want to get the highest average, you need to write something like:

```
        //get array of values and returns the average
        const getAverage = function(nums) {
        let sum = 0;
          for(let i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
            let el = nums[i];
            sum += el;
          }
          return sum / nums.length;
        }
        
        //get array of values and returns the max value
        const getMax = function(arr) {
        let max = arr[0]
        for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            if(arr[i] > max) { max = arr[i]}
          }
        return max
        }
    
    const arrayA = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
    const arrayB = [10000, -9998];
    const arrayC = [2, 100, 55, 19];
    const arrayD = [4, 8, 12];
    
    //get average for each array
    const averageA = getAverage(arrayA)
    const averageB = getAverage(arrayB)
    const averageC= getAverage(arrayC)
    const averageD = getAverage(arrayD)
    
    //get max average
    const result = getMax([averageA , averageB , averageC, averageD])
```